# c++ pragma omp critical(name)

Tags: c++, openmp, critical-section

Imagine I have a class method that contains a critical region :

```
class A{
    public:
        A(){};

        method(){
            #pragma omp critical(name)
                { //do something }
        }
}
```

Now I have two instances of `A`, ie. `A a1` and `A a2`. What is the behaviour
of `a1.method()` and `a2.method()` ? Can `{//do something}` be executed at the
same time ?

Ultimatly, I want to forbid a simultaneous call of `{//do something}` on the
same instance but to allow a simultaneous call of `{//do something}` on
different instance.

Comment: `A thread waits at the beginning of a critical region until no other thread is executing a critical region (anywhere in the program) with the same name.` Seems to be quite enough, additional synchronization is not required.

Answer (score 1):

The critical section is the same for all instances of the object - only one thread at a time will be able to enter.

To allow different instances to manage access separately, use a mutex owned by the instance. You can use the `omp_init_lock()` and the other `omp_xxx_lock()` functions, `std::mutex`, or another mutex implementation.